# How to redirect all pages of Site A to home page of Site B using .htaccess to track referrals using Google UTM

Tags: google-analytics, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I want 301 redirect from all pages of `SiteA.example` to Home Page of `SiteB.example` using `.htaccess` rewrite rule, Since I am not PHP guy I am not sure if below rule is correct

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.SiteB.example/?utm_campaign=domainnames&utm_medium=domain&utm_source=%{HTTP_HOST}" [L,R=301,QSA] [R=301,QSD,L]`

I am facing problem since I am not able to track `301 redirects` on `SiteB.example` as Google Analytics doesn't track it as this information is not passed on when 301 redirect is taking place.

So rewrite rule was suggested by someone on Stack Overflow but I want to get it right. Can you confirm that the above rewrite rule is fine?

Comment: Do SiteA and SiteB point to different servers? What _exactly_ do you want to redirect from/to? You say you want to redirect to the "home page", but what is `utm_campaign=domainnames&utm_medium=domain&utm_source=%{HTTP_HOST}` for? In the directive you posted you are explicitly preserving the query string from the original request - do you need this? "Since i am not PHP guy" - this has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @MrWhite, I want all pages of SiteA.com to be redirected to home page of siteB.com in a way so that i can redirect it with UTM so that i can track referral/ traffic source on SiteB.com on GA

Comment: So, this is really a GA problem? The `RewriteRule` directive itself is "OK" (except that you've duplicated the _flags_ argument - which I assume this is just a typo - but this won't actually cause an "error"). But you didn't answer my first question... "Do SiteA and SiteB point to different servers?" If not and SiteA/B is just an _alias_ then the above will naturally result in a redirect loop.

Comment: ... have you tested it? (NB: Don't use 301 _permanent_ redirects when testing; use 302s instead.)

Comment: @MrWhite, `Do SiteA and SiteB point to different servers?` Yes both are on different server...  I did resolve it by using following as part of query string `https://SiteB.com/?utm_campaign=SiteARedirect&utm_medium=301Redirect&utm_source=SiteAWebsite` now i am able to see traffic under `Traffic Sources` in Real Time and under `Acquisition-->Campaigns-->All Campaigns` before this it was not possible as 301 doesnt often pass this information in header so GA is not able to register it. So this is a way around to track source traffic in this scenario

Comment: This is the code in .httaccess `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://SiteB.com/?utm_campaign=SiteARedirect&utm_medium=301Redirect&utm_source=SiteAWebsite [R=301,L]`

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue. Please add your solution as an "answer" (and later accept it). You can simplify/optimise the regex to something like `^` (from `^(.*)$`), as there is no need to capture the URL-path in that rule. I would have thought you could have used `%{HTTP_HOST}` (or a variation of in order to canonicalise this), as you had initially, to represent `SiteAWebsite`?

Comment: @MrWhite sure will add that to Answer..

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works for me. This code was added to the .htaccess file and it redirected all the pages in Site A to the Home Page of Site B.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://SiteB.com/utm_campaign=SiteARedirect&utm_medium=301Redirect&utm_source=SiteAWebsite [R=301,L]
```